# Reading from multiple tables using Rob Conery's Massive

Tags: c#, sql, massive

I recently started using Rob Conery's Massive for reading from an Oracle database in C#.

It's working really well. However, recently I came across a problem when trying to perform an inner join. Usually you just do this to specify what table you are reading from:

```
public class Products:DynamicModel {

    public Products():base("northwind", "products","productid") {}
}
```

However, when performing an inner join you are reading from more than one table. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Products.Query in that given join query. It will give all the property needed. Just go through blog post *[http://rob.conery.io/2011/09/27/massives-dynamic-query-syntax](http://wekeroad.com/2011/09/27/massives-dynamic-query-syntax)*. This will help you out. It's from Rob Conery himself, who created Massive.

Comment: The link is broken. It would be better to summarise the crucial information in your answer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry. It was very early days of using SO. and Massive moved to another place lately so I guess Rob's link will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't actually need the specify the table name.

If you just leave it as an empty string like below, the join works perfectly fine.

```
public class Products:DynamicModel {

    public Products():base("northwind", "", "productid") {}}
```